# Android : How to set lock screen time programmatically?

Tags: android

I would like to change settings of Screnn_Off and lock screen.

No problem for screen of :

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 18000000);
```

But how to set time for screen lock ?